# How can I graph messages/sec from a total queued message Prometheus metric in Grafana?

Tags: prometheus, grafana

[image]

I am capturing a metric that represents total queued messages on a RabbitMQ queue. I can graph this using: `rabbitmq_queue_messages{queue="queuedmessage"}`.
How can I transform this to instead show messages/sec?

Answer (score 0):

Calculate rate, e.g.:

```
rate(rabbitmq_queue_messages{queue="queuedmessage"}[$__rate_interval])
```

Comment: This does not work because, as far as I understand the documentation and blog post on the Prometheus site, rate() only works on a positively increasing counter. The closest I have gotten to something functional is `(deriv(rabbitmq_queue_messages{queue="queuedmessage"}[1m]) * -1) > 0` of which I am not a fan.